# how to loop the response and concat the array if second array exist using es6

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

```
[
  {
    "details": {
      "name": "john",
      "point": "20"
    },

    "list": {
      "number": "30",

    }
  },
  {
    "details": {
      "name": "doe",
      "point": "25"
    },
    "list": {
      "number": "30",

    }
  }
]
```

i am getting a response from the store in the above format i am using selector to get the response, i would like to concat the second array if exist and dislay in the following format

```
{
  "details": [
    {
      "name": "john",
      "point": "20"
    },
    {
      "name": "doe",
      "point": "25"
    }
  ]
}
```

this is what i am trying to do please suggest thanks in advance

```
this.store.pipe(
        select(someselector), 
        filter(result => !!result), 
        map(r => { 
             if (result) { 
              //concat the array if exist;
              return result;
             } 
           }
        ));
```

Answer (score 1):

Concat it using the rest operator and return the data in required format.

```
if (result) {
  // concat if arr exist. let say array name is arr.
  result = {
    details: [...result, ...arr].map(d => {
      return {
        name: d.details.name,
        point: d.details.point,
      }
    })
  }
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

its very simple
Let consider your first array is

```
let arry1 = [{"details":{"name":"john","point":"20"},"list":{"number":"30",}},{"details":{"name":"doe","point":"25"},"list":{"number":"30",}}];
```

second array is

```
let newarr = [];
```

now push details from first array to second,

```
newarr.push(arrlist.map(ob=>{return ob.details}));
```

then newarr contains

```
[[{"name":"john","point":"20"},{"name":"doe","point":"25"}]]
```

Hope this is helpful for you

***Happy Coding***